# How to turn this mess into a tileable surface?

Tags: drywall, tiling

I want to tile this backsplash but the surface here is incredibly crumbly, and the more I pick at it the more falls off. I'm afraid of taking it off altogether as the kitchen/cabinet rails are built into it. Will PVA'ing it make it tileable? Or alternatively maybe glueing some plasterboard slab up onto which I can put the tiles?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Remove the backing. It's crumbling, and no support to anything. Cut it off at the edge of the cabinets, at least as far as the surface to be tiled.
2. That appears to be a high-moisture location. Gypsum plasterboard will not hold up well to that. You might use a cement board as backer, which is *far* more durable.

Comment: Are these 2 steps or are they options?

Comment: Do you just want to *hide* that crumbling mass??